# Do spinlocks really need DMB?

Tags: linux, synchronization, locking, arm, memory-barriers

I'm working with a dual Cortex-A9 system and I've been trying to
understand exactly why spinlock functions need to use DMB. It seems
that as long as the merging store buffer is flushed the lock value
should end up in the L1 on the unlocking core and the SCU should
either invalidate or update the value in the L1 of the other core.
This is enough to maintain coherency and safe locking right? And
doesn't STREX skip the merging store buffer anyway, meaning we don't
even need the flush?

DMB appears to be something of a blunt hammer, especially since it
defaults to the system domain, which likely means a write all the way
to main memory, which can be expensive.

Are the DMBs in the locks there as a workaround for drivers that don't
use smp_mb properly?

I'm currently seeing, based on the performance counters, about 5% of
my system cycles disappearing in stalls caused by DMB.

Comment: This may be a completely misguided comment because I'm not very experienced at such a low level of operation, but surely a spinlock is used to protect _other_ memory locations from multiple access (ones which may not be in the same cache page).. so although the spinlock itself may be coherent anyway, you still need a memory barrier to make sure that other memory accesses are coherent between caches.

Comment: OK I see what you mean but does that logic apply to the lock function as well as the unlock? Lock shouldn't have to wait for accesses outside of critical sections to complete.

Comment: In the unlock I would expect a full memory barrier before unlocking so that any changes that occur during the critical section are guaranteed to be flushed before the lock flag is updated, and that any read operations that occurred during the critical section to be completed before the lock flag is updated. Even beyond the caching issues, I think memory barriers are important to tell the CPU what sort of instruction reordering is allowable past different points in the program.

Comment: Yes, I see that's the case for unlock, but what about lock?

Comment: A lock operation would have to atomically test whether the lock is already owned and simultaneously take ownership of it. This on its own is probably enough to require a full memory barrier. You need a memory barrier to ensure that memory operations to the locked resource during the critical section do not instead happen before the lock sequence. And by "happen" I also extend the meaning to the full process of reading or writing which includes caching etc, which can happen long before the actual load or store instruction is executed.

Comment: LDREX handles the atomic test and set case without a DMB, but I see the logic on the rest of what your saying. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking there must be some type of implied memory barrier since LDREX needs to ensure coherence between multiple CPUs accessing the lock, but of course this isn't relevant since it doesn't imply an actual DMB which is what you were asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these articles may answer your question:

- [Locks, SWPs and two Smoking Barriers](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/169-locks-swps-and-two-smoking-barriers/)
- [Locks, SWPs and two Smoking Barriers (Part 2)](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/188-locks-swps-and-two-smoking-barriers-part-2/)

In particular:

> You will note the Data Memory Barrier (DMB) instruction that is issued once the lock has been acquired. The DMB guarantees that all memory accesses before the memory barrier will be observed by all of the other CPUs in the system before all memory accesses made after the memory barrier. This makes more sense if you consider that once a lock has been acquired, a program will then access the data structure(s) locked by the lock. The DMB in the lock function above ensures that accesses to the locked data structure are observed after accesses to the lock.

Answer (score 2):

The DMB is needed in the SMP case because the other processor may see the memory accesses happening in a different order without it, i.e. accesses from inside the critical section may happen before the lock is taken from the point-of-view of the second core.

So the second core could see itself holding the lock and also see updates from inside the cricital section running on the other core, breaking consistency.

Comment: This is mainly caused by the out of order execution, right?